# calculate the sum of months from a fiscal year horizontally from one list to a summary list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

List 1- Food

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1000 | 1000 | 3000 |
| sum | sum | sum | sum |

This list is a category and lists 2-Clothes, 3-Water, 4-Internet, 5-Misc are the same I need the sum of the columns of this list to be transposed to the summary list

then summarize it all on a summary list:

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 10000 | 10000 | 30000 |
| 10000 | 10000 | 10000 | 30000 |
| 10000 | 10000 | 10000 | 30000 |
| 10000 | 10000 | 10000 | 30000 |
| 10000 | 10000 | 10000 | 30000 |
| sum | sum | sum | sum |

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a calculated column in SharePoint list based on data in another SharePoint list.

---

So, your requirements cannot be achieved using SharePoint OOTB functionalities. You need to develop the custom solution for this.

If you want to calculate it periodically & update it SharePoint, you can run scheduled power automate flow which will do the calculations & updated the data in summary list.

---

If it is not mandatory to show the summary report in SharePoint itself, you can create a canvas power apps application using the SharePoint data & do the calculation using power apps formulas.

Comment: that is what I am doing right now. I am trying to create a power automate flow for this.

Comment: ok great. let us know if you need any help with it.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: I am stuck at sorting the array from each month column to perform a sum data operation.